# Peak Detection on ECG signal

Tags: filters, noise, wavelet, continuous-signals, denoising

I've been working on a ECG signal collected during exercise through my chest mount heart rate monitor. My goal is to accurately detect the location of the R-wave; R-wave is the narrow peak similar to the ones I circled in red.

Can you suggest any method for preprocessing the data so that it will be easier to extract the signal?

I have tried wavelet transform but I am not getting any luck.

[image]

You can download the data [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xxdgkkp2kp4diya/AAC5-xmuW7MpI57-rT8EARP2a?dl=0). Sampling frequency is 150 Hz.

Comment: I would start by reviewing [Physionet's](https://physionet.org/physiotools/) resources. Not only the toolkit but the papers they have produced on QRS detection (Look for "George Moody"). In a nutshell, (possibly detrend), rectify, integrate, apply threshold (possibly adaptive). This will give you the R peaks with very good accuracy.

Comment: I've went ahead and removed all the chatter from your question; it was actually making it worse.

Comment: haha @MarcusMüller thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A typical approach would be the Pan-tompkins algorithm. You can also apply a first order low pass filter or a mean filter to improve results.